# How does this simple copy program work

Tags: java

I'm supposed to write a program which works similar to the Unix cp command. I found this piece of code, but can't really figure out how/ why it works.

```
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int i = 0;
        while ((i = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, i);
        }
```

How does the while loop work? I suppose it reads from the InputStream in 1024 byte portions, saves them to the byte array buf and then writes buf to the new file.

But what does

```
in.read(buf);
```

assign to i? And how does the while loop through the whole file(what tells in.read(buf) to read the next 1024 bytes of data and not the same first 1024 over and over)?

Thanks,
P.

Comment: maybe read the documentation: in.read() returns the number of bytes read. if no bytes can be read, it returns -1

Comment: @x4rf41 yes.you should add that as answer.

Comment: If you don't know what a method does, it is usually best to try to read it's documentation.  An alternative is to use your debugger to step through the code and see what it does.

Comment: The file position move as you keep reading...if you read 1024 bytes the file position moves to next byte after 1024 and this position is maintained by the inputstream...

Comment: Thanks. I read the documentation, I just wasn't aware that the file position moves with reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So lets go step by step, yes?

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int i = 0;
while ((i = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
    out.write(buf, 0, i);
}
```

The first four lines aren't hard. Create an in and out stream. Allocate a buffer of size 1024.

The next step is the while loop. The first thing executed is:

```
(i = in.read(buf))
```

This reads into the buffer, `buf` as much as it can, then returns the bytes read. This is then assigned to `i`, so `i` is the number of bytes in `buf` that are from the stream.

Note that the `read()` call will advance the stream. This means that it will not repeat bytes. So if your stream is:

```
1 51 23 10 6 73
```

You might read in

```
1 51
```

Which returns `2` (the number read in). The stream is now:

```
23 10 6 73
```

Back to the loop! After reading in from the stream, we check if there was anything at all read into `buf`

```
... != -1
```

Note that

```
(i = in.read(buf))
```

Evaluates to the value of `i`, so the loop condition is `while (i != -1)`. The reason this statement evaluates as such is similar to the reason we can do:

```
a = b = 1;
```

Which is really:

```
a = (b = 1);
```

The next line is pretty straightforward. Write all the bytes in `buf` from `0` to `i`.

So in the end, this loop can be rewritten as:

```
while(true){
    int i = in.read(buf);
    if(i == -1)
        break;
    out.write(buf, 0, i);
}
```

Comment: That is a fine answer..  :)

Comment: Thanks, I simply wasn't aware of the fact that read() advances the stream. :)

Answer (score 1):

> And how does the while loop through the whole file(what tells
>   in.read(buf) to read the next 1024 bytes of data and not the same
>   first 1024 over and over)?

```
while ((i = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, i);
}
```

is equivalent to :

```
i = in.read();
while (i != -1) {
        out.write(buf, 0, i);
        i = in.read();
}
```

Comment: @downvoter Could you light me please ?

Comment: I guess by 'light' you mean 'enlighten', and not being the down-voter, I can't.  I will +1 though..  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes, I mean that thanks =).

Answer (score 1):

```
in.read(buf)
```

Returns the number of bytes that were read into buf. If the end of the file was reached before, it returns -1.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()

Files have a pointer that is moved with every access (read/write), so the next read/write will start where the last one ended.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException
```

> Reads up to b.length bytes of data from this input stream into an
>   array of bytes. This method blocks until some input is available.
>
> Returns the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there
>   is no more data because the end of the file has been reached.

The while loop is checking that there is still data to be read and `i` is being assigned the number of bytes that were read. It is then used to write the correct number of bytes to the output stream.

```
pubilc void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException
```

> Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off
>   to this file output stream.